# How can I show encrypted field value in Laravel Nova?

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I'm saving a password value on a "site" model using the Password::make field.

I would then like to display this password decrypted when a user with the correct privileges (which I already have working) presses an inline button "show password" on the detail view or index view.

I've tried using :

```
Text::make('Decrypted', function () {
    return decrypt($this->password);
})
```

But unfortunately this gives me an "incorrect payload" error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hashes Are Irreversible**

Your password was hashed and **not** encrypted.

You should now that Laravel uses **one way** hash functions.

> A one-way hash function is a mathematical function which takes a
>   plain text input string and converts it into a fixed-length
>   binary sequence. Furthermore, a one-way hash function is designed in
>   such a way that it is hard to reverse the process, that is, to find a
>   string that hashes to a given value (hence the name one-way.) A good
>   hash function also makes it hard to find two strings that would
>   produce the same hash value.

Besides

> Showing a user's password on screen, especially in a web app, is
>   likely a security vulnerability and may render the system vulnerable
>   to script injection, screen reader, or man in the middle attacks.

[Read more](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/80306/how-to-show-password-on-a-users-profile-page)

Comment: I thought that might be the case... So instead of using a Password::make, is there anyway I can use Text::make and use encrypt('value') instead? My goal is to have the passwords encrypted on the db but in the frontend they can be visible as the site will only be accessable locally by an authorized user.

Comment: **You should NOT** 
This is a security antipattern.

See more  [How to show password on a user's profile page](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/80306/how-to-show-password-on-a-users-profile-page)

Comment: I understand that this may at first look like a security antipattern but for the specific application in mind, it is not really. It's basically a database of passwords for the admin's various devices. We all know that a lot of admins store their passwords in password protected excel spreadsheets (yes you know who you are). This app just offers a more elegant way of storing the data with search capabilities. However just for peace of mind, I would like to still store the passwords encrypted in the db.